# How to align images to a grid. (I want to make a product list with pictures that when clicked they link to corresponding pages)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been given a task to create a product list from work. Currently it is in the format of a excel sheet with about 15 pages. On the first page there is a group of 10 icons. Since it is on excel the images can be arranged how you like. Once clicked the images lead to the corresponding page with product codes and data.

I have been tasked to convert that product list into a HTML page.I want to be able to have a grid of pictures just like on excel, so they appear like a product list.

**What I've tried:**

I have tried using div class column and div class row but that didnt seem to work. I've also tried putting the images into a table but that didnt work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Neverfail CSS.css">    
</head>
<body>
<h1>NeverFail Product List</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="HOME- NF.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<br>


<a href="Water, Casks & Delivery Fee.html">
  <img title="Water, Casks & Delivery Fee" src="Icons/NF_W.png" alt="Water Bottles, Casks & Delivery Fee" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Water, Casks & Delivery Fee</figcaption>
</a>


<a href="Wcoolers.html">
  <img src="Icons/wcoolers.png" alt="Water Coolers" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
  <figcaption>Water Coolers</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="cups+acc.png">
  <img src="Icons/cups+acc.png" alt="Cups & Accessories" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
  <figcaption>Cups & Accessories</figcaption>
</a>


<a href="ceramicwell.png">
  <img src="Icons/ceramicwell.png" alt="Ceramic Water Well & Water Only" style="width:80px;height:110px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Ceramic Water Well & Water Only</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="racks.png">
  <img src="Icons/racks.png" alt="Racks" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Racks</figcaption>
</a>

<br>

<a href="filters.png">
  <img src="Icons/filters.png" alt="Aqua Vital Filters" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Aqua Vital Filters</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="MTF.png">
  <img src="Icons/MTF.png" alt="Mount Franklin" style="width:90px;height:120px;border:0">
</a>

<a href="p/ade.png">
  <img src="Icons/pade.png" alt="Powerade" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Powerade</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="Cocacola.png">
  <img src="Icons/Cocacola.png" alt="Coca Cola Range" style="width:180px;height:100px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Coca Cola Range</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="grinders.png">
  <img src="Icons/grinders.png" alt="Grinders Coffee" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Grinders Coffee</figcaption>
</a>

<br>

<a href="simplicitea.png">
  <img src="Icons/simplicitea.png" alt="Simplicitea" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Simplicitea</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="NTretailrange.png">
  <img src="Icons/NTretailrange.png" alt="Northern Territory Retail Range" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Northern Territory Retail Range</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="Promos.png">
  <img src="Icons/Promos.png" alt="Promotions & New Customer Offers" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Promotions & New Customer Offers</figcaption>
</a>

<a href="Monster.png">
  <img src="Icons/Monster.png" alt="Monster" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0">
   <figcaption>Monster</figcaption>
</a>

<br><br><br>


<a href="Icons/Logo background Hor.png" >
  <img src="Icons/Logo background Hor.png" alt="Monster" style="width:1400px;height:150px;border:0">
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I would to create a dynamic clickable grid of pictures.

Comment: Have you considered using Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the CSS flex layout could help you.

To use flex, you need to have a parent container for your  "blocks", so put a single `<div>` around all your `<a..>` blocks and assign a `display: flex;` to that div. That should be enough to give you something quite satisfying.

If you need more info about how flex can be tweaked, check: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Edit:
Also, you might consider Rachel Andrew's "The New CSS Layout" book available from A Book Apart. It is an *excellent* review of where HTML layout comes from, where it is now and where it is headed, with very practical examples and lots of references.